# Read dynamic attachment from jsp with struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts

In our system we have a form where you can add attachments to upload.
this will result in something like this.

```
<div id="multiattach">
<input name="uploads[1]" class="multiattachinput" type="file">
<input name="uploads[0]" class="multiattachinput" type="file">
</div>
```

Where the number of inputs is dynamic.
When the form is submitted it is handled by a struts validatorform
and the above is handle with

```
     public void setUploads(int iIndex, FormFile formFile){ 
            //Handle the file 
     }
```

This method is called once for every attachment.
This has worked but now I have changed Eclipse and now for some reason when the form is submitted the above setUploads is never called.
I have tried to import all the same jars and use the same tomcat but apparently something must have changed.
Any ideas why this is not working, everything else in the system works as previous.
If I can't figure out why this isn't working maybe someone has another idea about how to submit these files.

Comment: OK I know what the difference is now. In eclispe -windows -preferences - installed JRE I had 1.8 in the one that doesn't work. If I switch to 1.6 the setUploads method gets called again.
Don't know how to fix this since I don't want to go back to 1.6 at this point. Very frustrating.

Comment: OK I actually managed to fix this. It turns out that if you have a method called getUploads then for some reason the setUploads is never called..
I renamed my getUploads and now everything works.
Maybe this will help someone some day.